# What is the best way of connecting a react-native app to firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am making a react-native app and I was wondering what the best way is to connect to firebase?  I found some resources here at https://rnfirebase.io/ and to me it looks good but I figured I would ask in case someone feels different.  Also, will this work running my app on a device with expo?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the firebase, you must detached the `Expo`.

These Unimodules were designed to be used in detached ExpoKit & vanilla React Native. Each module has detailed instructions on how to install, you should refer to the [React Native Firebase docs on more detailed usage](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/getting-started.)

1. `expo eject`
2. `yarn add expo-firebase-app`

**Usage**

```js
import firebase from 'expo-firebase-app';
import 'expo-firebase-database';
firebase.database()
```

```js
import firebase from 'expo-firebase-app';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
  authDomain: "<YOUR-AUTH-DOMAIN>",
  databaseURL: "<YOUR-DATABASE-URL>",
  storageBucket: "<YOUR-STORAGE-BUCKET>"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

### Authentication Usage

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'expo-firebase-app';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          isAuthenticated: true,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    // If the user has not authenticated
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to my awesome app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Matt123 If my answer was helpful, would you please check and select the 'V' and arrow?

Comment: There is no need to expo eject,  firebase can be used as an api endpoint.

Comment: @SuleymanSah This is not the method of use recommended by the Expo.

Comment: why not recommended?

Comment: @SuleymanSah The reason was written in the comment in your reply.

Comment: Thanks @hong develop!  My main question now is how to use firebase authentication.  It's token-based, so can I follow the web instructions or do I have to do ios and android instructions?

Comment: @Matt123 Yes Please refer this https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/auth/getting-started

Comment: @Matt123 I also edited in my answer that Certification for example for you.